# Bootstrap: overlapping modal should not freeze underlying modal from scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I KNOW that Bootstrap discourages overlapping modals. I hacked together a site really quickly to help with the whole coronavirus thing, and so my focus was on speed not getting everything perfect. Consequently today someone pointed out a bug. Normally what happens with a Bootstrap modal:

- Bootstrap sets scroll automatically a based on modal content, that is if content requires scroll, I guess the appropriate CSS is added
- When a modal is open, the background content (that's covered by tinted overlay), is not scrollable
- Once the modal is closed, the background content becomes scrollable again

My problem right now is that in my overlapping modal situation, the second modal that opens on top of the first one causes the content of the first modal to stay unscrollable, even when the second, overlapping modal is closed.

My desired behavior is that when the second modal is closed, the first modal returns to "default", that is, if the content requires scrollability, the scroll returns.

Here's a live site: https://www.giftcardsforsmallbusinesses.com/

1. Click to follow the modal: *If you would like to be listed here, click here* (ensure you're viewing this on a screen when there modal content requires scrolling, which is most screens... it's a lot of content)
2. On the modal that pops up, find #4 on How It Works, and click the *bonus value*
3. A second, small modal will pop up
4. Now close the second, smaller modal
5. You'll notice now that the first modal: Are you a small business owner? is no longer scrollable. Curiously, the background content, the original page, is now scrollable

I feel like there's a quick & dirty answer here... I can just inject something where it's like

```
PSEUDOCODE
$("#second-modal").on("close", function() {
  $("#first-modal").resetDefault()
})
```

But I don't have enough experience with Twitter Bootstrap to know how to do this, and I couldn't find the answer in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it...

```
$('.modal').on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) { 
    if ($('.modal:visible').length) { 
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    }
});
```

When you close the overlapped bonus modal, it removes the body class `.modal-open` by default (not knowing there is another modal below it). This class applies `overflow:hidden;` to the body and enables modals to scroll independently.

So the above script is basically adding the class again when the bonus modal is closed/hidden.

---

Try this, this is directly targeting the bonus modal hidden event.

```
$('#expirationModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('BODY').addClass('modal-open');
})
```

Comment: thanks! this fixes the issue of the body being scrollable, but not that of the underlying first modal being NOT scrollable. guessing some class is just being removed there as well that's applying to all modals?

Comment: On your website, if I open the first modal, then the bonus modal, and then close the bonus modal, your first modal does not scroll. But if I add `.modal-open` to the body html tag using the inspector, your modal then becomes scrollable.

Comment: I've just added a more direct option in my answer which should hopefully work, though only for this scenario

Comment: you know what I figured it out. That wasn't the issue. The fact that you did it in inspector clued me in. It's because the modal starts out invisible so the handler doesn't hook in. The original code works, just needed to add like so: `$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", '.modal', function (e) { `

Comment: Using document is always the one full proof way of hitting any newly added dom elements which surprises me the first code didn't work because body is already present. But your way is even more solid so glad you figured it out.

Comment: This means you can now stack as many modals as like  though imo you should add the class `.modal-dialog-centered` onto `.modal-dialog` to sweeten the look